# WKWebView - WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage on document.body.scrollHeight

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I try to load content with wkwebview. Everything works fine, I suceed to get scrollHeight on `didFinish` delegate from wkwebview.

But that doesn't work on url that loads .pdf like this one : http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf

Here is my code :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Adapt scroll view height
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.readyState", completionHandler: { (complete, error) in
            if complete != nil {
                self.webInfoView.evaluateJavaScript("document.body.scrollHeight", completionHandler: { (height, error) in
```

I tried both document.body.scrollHeight and document.documentElement.scrollHeight

When I load PDF files, error contains : 
`Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=1, WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.documentElement.scrollHeight'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=25, WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript exception occurred}`
and height is nil : 0

I think this is DOM problem ?

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Yaman no, can't find :(

Comment: @Vjardel Any luck?